# UISearchController search bar doesn't get focus

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In my project, If a controller (containing UISearchController) is pushed second time on to the navigation stack, Search bar can't seem to get focus. The following GIF recoding demonstrates what I am talking about:

[image: As you can see, when search screen is pushed to the navigation stack the second time, I can't tap in the search bar]

As you can see, when search screen is pushed to the navigation stack the second time (by tapping the magnifying glass), I can't tap in the search bar anymore.

**Code to reproduce the issue:** If you'd like to look at the code, You can [download the minimal project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6845322/SearchBarIssue.zip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your UISearchControllerDelegate

```
    class SearchController: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        self.definesPresentationContext = false
    }
```

in the storyboard also need to change the segue from Show Push, to Show Replace

or use extensions however the cool kids are doing it now.

Comment: Dont push the search screen onto the Navigation stack. Instead present it modally

Comment: I had to change `definesPresentationContext` from `true` to `false`. that fixed it, I also changed the segue time from `Show` to `Show Detail`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
 }

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }
```

it working fine for me, but not sure is it good solution or not?